# jQuery.fn.extend check if first param is 'document' or 'string' (selector)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jquery plugin like this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    myPlugin: function() {
        //Something...
    }
});
```

If I use:

- `$(document).myPlugin();` is Ok
- `$(parent.document).myPlugin();` is Ok
- `$("#myId").myPlugin();` should fail
- `$(window).myPlugin();` should fail
- `$(parent).myPlugin();` should fail

I tried

```
$.fn.extend({
    myPlugin: function() {
        console.log(this.selector);
    }
});
```

But in `$(document)` and `$(window)` is showed empty.

How check if first param is `document` or `parent.document` (for pop-up or iframes)?

Comment: Would `this.selector.toString() === "[object HTMLDocument]"` works?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thans, but not work :( - is empty in console. I tried this `console.log(typeof this.selector);` too and is showed `string` in console. In other words, `this.selector` returns a empty string.

Comment: Yeah, I skipped the part where you said it showed empty. You might try something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/52y76d2v/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It's works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if (this[0] instanceof Document || this[0] instanceof Window) {
    alert ('OK');
} else {
    alert ('Not OK');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it's works in all examples ... But a note: I replace `this` by `var obj = this[0];`.